# Cannot create Azure HDInsight cluster with Hive metastore using Powershell

Tags: azure, hive, azure-hdinsight, azure-powershell, metastore

I get error when I try to create Azure HDInsight cluster using powershell cmdlet:

```
New-AzureRmHDInsightClusterConfig  `
    | Add-AzureRmHDInsightMetastore `
        -SqlAzureServerName "$sqlDatabaseServerName.database.windows.net" `
        -DatabaseName $hiveMetaStoreDBName `
        -Credential $sqlServerCred `
        -MetastoreType HiveMetaStore `
    | New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster `
        -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
        -HttpCredential $clusterCreds `         
        -ClusterName $clusterName `
        -Location $location `
        -ClusterType $clusterType `
        -OSType $OSType `
        -Version "$hdVersion" `
        -SshCredential $clusterCreds `
        -DefaultStorageAccountName "$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net" `
        -DefaultStorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey `
        -ClusterSizeInNodes $clusterNodes
```

Looks like parameters are not recognized by powershell because it asks to input them (see below). I input required parameters (Location, ClusterName, ClusterSizeInNodes) and then error occurs.

```
cmdlet New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster at command pipeline position 3
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
Location: West Europe
ClusterName: xxxxxxxxx
ClusterSizeInNodes: 1
New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster : BadRequest: ParameterNullOrEmpty,Parameter 'ASVAccount.AccountName' cannot be null or 
empty.
At line:117 char:11
+         | New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster `
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Hyak.Common.CloudException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.HDInsight.NewAzureHDInsightClusterCom 
   mand
```

Does somebody know why its happens or what is wrong in smdlet?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems like your `$storageAccountName` parameter to the `New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster` cmdlet is Null or Empty, you may want to inspect further on this.

Besides, I would also strongly recommend you to specify the `-DefaultStorageContainer` to the `New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster` cmdlet as well. This will ensures that the cmdlet will be able to resolve the FQDN of your storage account Uri.

E.g. [asv://YourDefaultContainer@YourDefaultStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/](http://asv://YourDefaultContainer@YourDefaultStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: $storageAccountName parameter is not Null or Empty. All other parameters are not Null or Empty too. Also when I'm trying to create cluster without Hive metastore (see cmdlet below) everything is OK.

Comment: New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster `
 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
 -HttpCredential $clusterCreds `
    -ClusterName $clusterName `
    -Location $location `
 -OSType Linux `
 -ClusterType Hadoop `
 -Version "3.2" `
 -SshCredential $clusterCreds `
   -DefaultStorageAccountName "$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net" `
    -DefaultStorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey `
    -DefaultStorageContainer $containerName  `
    -ClusterSizeInNodes $clusterNodes

Comment: No, the last command works properly and creates cluster successfully. But I need to use Hive metastore.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use below command for Cluster with Hive Metastore.

Here is a working PowerShell script, to be used with Azure ARM PowerShell, 1.0.1 or later – you can install Azure RM PS via web platform installer or follow this blog https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azps-1-0/ 


Add-AzureRmAccount
$MyClusterName = "clustername";
$MyClusterLocation = "East US 2";
$NumClusterNodes = 2;
$MyClusterVersion = "3.2";
$MyHDInsightUserName = ""
$MyHDInsightPwd = ""
$MySqlAzureUserName = ""
$MySqlAzurePwd = ""
$MySqlAzureServerName = "*.database.windows.net"
$MySqlAzureDbName = "Dbtest"
$MyDefaultContainerName = "tastoreps"
$clusterResourceGroupName = "dirg"
# Use the correct Azure Subscription!
$subid = ""
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subid
# Storage key
$primaryStorageAcctName = "toragesouth"
$primaryStorageResourceGroupName = "storagerg"
# you need to use an ARM based storage as the primary account , classic storage won’t work as a primary account, known issue
$storageAccountKey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $primaryStorageResourceGroupName -Name $primaryStorageAcctName | %{ $_.Key1 }
# credentials
$HdInsightPwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $MyHDInsightPwd -AsPlainText -Force
$HdInsightCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($MyHDInsightUserName, $HdInsightPwd)
$SqlAzurePwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $MySqlAzurePwd -AsPlainText -Force
$SqlAzureCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($MySqlAzureUserName, $SqlAzurePwd)
$config = New-AzureRmHDInsightClusterConfig -ClusterType Hadoop | 
Add-AzureRmHDInsightMetastore -SqlAzureServerName $MySqlAzureServerName -DatabaseName $MySqlAzureDbName -Credential $SqlAzureCreds -MetastoreType HiveMetastore | 
Add-AzureRmHDInsightMetastore -SqlAzureServerName $MySqlAzureServerName -DatabaseName $MySqlAzureDbName -Credential $SqlAzureCreds -MetastoreType OozieMetastore 
$config.DefaultStorageAccountName="$StorageAcctName.blob.core.windows.net"
$config.DefaultStorageAccountKey=$storageAccountKey
#create cluster
New-AzureRmHDInsightCluster -config $config -OSType Windows -clustername $MyClusterName -HttpCredential $HdInsightCreds -DefaultStorageContainer $MyDefaultContainerName -Location $MyClusterLocation -ResourceGroupName $clusterResourceGroupName -ClusterSizeInNodes $NumClusterNodes -Version $MyClusterVersion
```

Comment: This script creates cluster but without metastores, Do you have some ideas why metastores are not created?